# Java swing gridbaglayout not filling one row entirely

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have a panel that uses a GridbagLayout display to place 3 objects: A button, combobox, and a scrollPane. I want the button and the combobox to be on the same row (row 0) and occupy the entire row. This is how I have placed them in the panel:

```
GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gc.insets.set(10, 0, 10, 10);
add(comboBox, gc);
gc.gridx = 1;
gc.weightx = 1;
gc.insets.set(10, 0, 10, 0);
add(okButton, gc);
```

Now I want the scrollpane to  occupy the entire bottom row (row 1). This is what I did:

```
gc.gridx = 0;
gc.gridy = 1;
gc.weighty = 1;
//gc.insets.set(0, 0, 0, 0);
add(scrollPane, gc);
```

However this only makes the scrollpane occupy the first column of the bottom row, so it is always aligned with the combobox. How do I make it such that it occupies the entire bottom row and not just the first column? Willing to try a different layout if that will help. The idea I have is to create a new panel that just contains the scrollPane and add that to the current panel, but I would much rather not do that if there is an alternative

Here is the current panel

[image: Image of the current panel]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `gridwidth= 2` to effectively set a column span for the description.